# How to pause the mediaelementjs player on a button click?

Tags: jquery, mediaelement

i am using mediaelementjs to play video on my web page. I want pause the media if it playing on a button click.i tried do it but didn't work.

here is the code:

```
    var my_media=jQuery('audio,video').mediaelementplayer(
{
    success: function(player, node)
    {
        jQuery('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType)


    }


});

jQuery('#rightControlarrow').click(function(){

my_media.pause();

});
```

Comment: plz provide you solution with some working code stuff.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with this plugin, but I think that the multiple selectors ('audio,video') are your problem.  This could be causing some DOM confusion as to which element is being referenced when you call 'pause'. So try just adding one per object (i.e. $('video').mediaelementlayer(. . .);

Press F12 in your browser to catch JavaScript errors and also make use of the "error" property of MediaElement to give yourself some feedback when something goes wrong.

Also, I don't see where you are calling the play method ( mediaElement.play();).

If you want to post more script and markup I will be happy to take a look tomorrow to see if there are other issues.

Take care,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
my_media = new Array();
jQuery('audio,video').mediaelementplayer(
{
    success: function(player, node)
    {
        jQuery('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);

my_media.push(player);





    }


});

jQuery('#rightControlarrow').click(function(){

my_media[0].pause();


});
```